# beveling edge trick

Tags: modeling

Blend file link: https://pasteall.org/blend/f33b643f7ae540fdac2f0aade9e3bc23

Is there a way to bevel the corner, kinda like how I drew the red lines so that the bevel comes to a point.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

I tried to answer given below and this is how it turns out, but I'm getting some weird stuff forming at the tip of where the bevels meet at. If I select edges 1-4 then the 2nd image is how it turns out. If I select all 5 edges then the 3rd image is how it looks and it looks even worse. How can I fix this. Both versions have the same bevel settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I might try using a gradient bevel weight to make the modifier do this.

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/7ap31gG) the sort of thing? (It's not a bevel, it's loosening / tightening holding loops on subdiv.)

Answer (score 6):

Either using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> modelling, or via a modifier, you can sketch out the shape of a bevel profile with edge-loops, and use  Bevel's 'Percent' setting...

[image]

which permits asymmetrical bevels. You can delete the guide-loops, if necessary, (after applying the modifier, if used).

Thanks to @Gordon Brinkmann for nudging this edit...

For a less destructive approach, when using the *Bevel* modifier, you can take the percentage to 100 and incorporate the guide-loops into the Bevel, by following up with a *Weld* modifier:

[image]

(Keep an eye on the *Weld* threshold)

Comment: Can you check the screenshots I've added? It's acting weird, and I don't know if I'm doing what you suggested wrong.

Comment: Hi, @AlexWillis21 . This looks like an inside corner? I'm finding it hard to decipher.. maybe share a file on https://pasteall.org/blend/, or illustrate from a little bit further away so we can see the overall shape?

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to provide the files. I had to remake it also because I forgot to save and overnight my pc did an update. I put the link up above for everyone to see.